# Height of status bar in WatchKit

Tags: objective-c, ios8, watchkit

How do you find the height of the status bar in a `WKInterfaceController` programmatically?

I'm trying to find the viewable area in a `WKInterfaceController` so `[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice].screenBounds.size.height` - `(status bar height)`.

Answer (score 2):

To get the current device size use `[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice].screenBounds)`. So you will need to minus your view's contentFrame from the overall screen bounds and you will get the status bar size.

Note: This will work if you're not using page-based navigation

Comment: Seems to be 38px for both watches.

Comment: I'm getting 19 pts (38px) for 38mm and 21 puts (42px) for 42mm.